# Hadoop EOF exception after Map step

Tags: hadoop, eof

I'm runnig Hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode. My new MR jobs throws EOF exception after Map step is complete in DataInputStream.readFully() method. The input/output formats are the same - SequenceFile. The similiar job runs fine, but the new one fails.

Stacktrace:

`java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:180)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:152)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1520)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1474)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:646)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInf`

I've fixed this issue, it was called by few corrupted Sequence files in HDFS input folder

Comment: Do you have custom Writables in your SequenceFile ?

Comment: Can you post a full stacktrace? And any relevant code you've written?

Comment: My key for map output implemets WritableComparable<T>.

Comment: Your Key or Value writable types probably have a difference in serialization between the write and readFields methods - can you post the K,V object types, and code for the readField / write methods if possible?

Comment: Thanks, guys. The problem was caused by broken sequence files in HDFS

Comment: I am having the same problem. I am using a custom data type by implementing Writable Interface. Like this `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);job.setMapOutputValueClass(TwitterData.class);`. Is there any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: I got the same problem. How did you solve it?