# Hive load data from multiple directories and dynamically create partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am storing data in Hadoop according to the date they were created, so I have multiple directories
on HDFS that are created  based on the format **/data/{year}/{month}/{day}**.
I wish to load these data in Hive (periodically) and create the corresponding partitions. For the moment I am experimenting with several approaches like the one below

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE tablename (...)
PARTITIONED BY (year STRING, month STRING, day STRING)
LOCATION '/data';

ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PARTITION(year='2014', month='10', day='13') LOCATION '/data/2014/10/13';
```

but with this approach I need to **manually** create each partition with the ALTER command. Is there any way to automate and parameterize this process (and put it in a workflow) to dynamically load data into Hive partitions for each one of the sub-directories ?

Comment: Check out if the solution here helps... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148187/hive-loading-in-partitioned-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a **msck repair table** ? This should automatically load all the partitions in the subdirectory. See here : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RecoverPartitions(MSCKREPAIRTABLE)

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I needed, the only thing I needed to do was to rename the input directories to work (format /partitionkey=partitionvalue/... )

Comment: I don't think any command can do that automatically. This you might have to rename while inserting the data itself.

Comment: Yes of course I just did that and it worked. Just wrote that for completeness if anyone has the same issues

Comment: @ypanag can you please share the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a dynamic partition in your case , you need to do the following while defining the partition columns

1. For date - Define the partition as day(string date).
2. For month - Define the partition as month(string date)
3. For year - Define as year(string date).

Hope you understood the concept. Hope this helps you

Comment: Thing is I am able to create the partitions, my problem is that I have to do it everyday manually (with process described above). Ideally I would want to somehow create some kind of automation (e.g. a script) to load my new data into Hive everyday