# hive - partitioning table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have created a hive table with the query -

```
create table studpart4(id int, name string) partitioned by (course string, year int) row format delimited fields terminated by '\t' lines terminated by '\n' stored as textfile;
```

Created successfully.

Loaded data with below command -

`load data local inpath '/scratch/hive_inputs/student_input_1.txt' overwrite into table studpart4 partition(course='cse',year=2);`

And my input data file looks like -

```
 101    student1    cse 1

 102    student2    cse 2

 103    student3    eee 3

 104    student4    eee 4

 105    student5    cse 1

 106    student6    cse 2

 107    student7    eee 3

 108    student8    eee 4

 109    student9    cse 1

 110    student10   cse 2
```

But output is displayed as (of `select * from studpart4`) --

```
 101    student1    cse 2

 102    student2    cse 2

 103    student3    eee 2

 104    student4    eee 2

 105    student5    cse 2

 106    student6    cse 2

 107    student7    eee 2

 108    student8    eee 2

 109    student9    cse 2

 110    student10   cse 2
```

Why does the last column is all 2.  Why did it get changed  and updating wrongly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13224581/2079249

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you are displayed is exactly what you told Hive to do with your data.

In your first command, you are creating a partitioned table `studpart4` with two columns, `id` and `name`, and two partitioned keys, `course` and `year` (which once created, behave like regular columns). Now, in your second command, what you are doing is this:

```
load data local inpath '/scratch/hive_inputs/student_input_1.txt' overwrite into table studpart4 partition(course='cse',year=2)
```

Which basically means "**copy** all the data from `student_input_1.txt` into the table `studpart4` and set all the values of column `course` to 'cse' and all the values of column `year` to '2'". Internally, Hive will create a directory structure which will contain your partition keys. Your data will be stored in a directory like this one:

```
.../studpart4/course=cse/year=2/
```

I suspect that what you really want is Hive to detect the column values of `course`and `year` in your `.txt` file and set the right values for you. In order to perform that, you have to use [dynamic partitioning](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-DynamicPartitionInserts) of your tables and follow an strategy of `loading` your data into an external table, and then use an `INSERT OVERWRITE INTO TABLE` command to store the data into your `studpart4` table. The link that BigDataLearner posted in a comment describes this strategy.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent.  Thanks for the detailed explanation.  I'm clarified now.