# Loading in path file to a partitioned table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to load a file locally into Hive by running this command:

`LOAD DATA INPATH '/data/work/hive/staging/ExampleData.csv' INTO TABLE tablename;`

which gives me the error:

> SemanticException [Error 10062]: Need to specify partition columns
>   because the destination table is partitioned (state=42000,code=10062)

[An answer I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148187/hive-loading-in-partitioned-table) suggests creating an intermediate table then letting dynamic partitioning kick in to load into a partitioned table.

I've created a table that matches the data and truncated it:

```
create table temptablename as select * from tablename;
truncate table temptablename
```

Then loaded the data using:

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/data/work/hive/staging/ExampleData.csv' INTO TABLE temptablename;
```

How do I 'kick in' dynamic partitioning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1.Load data into temptablename(without partition)
create table temptablename(col1,col2..);
LOAD DATA INPATH '/data/work/hive/staging/ExampleData.csv' INTO TABLE 
temptablename;

now once you have data in intermediate table ,you can kick in dynamic 
partitioning using following command.

2.INSERT into tablename PARTITION(partition_column) select * from 
temptablename;
```

Comment: does the order of column matters?

Comment: yes the order of columns has to be aligned with destination table's schema.