# Hive load multiple partitioned HDFS file to table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hive-partitions, hiveddl

I have some twice-partitioned files in HDFS with the following structure:

```
/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations/datekey=20210506/coeff=0.5/data.parquet
/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations/datekey=20210506/coeff=0.75/data.parquet
/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations/datekey=20210506/coeff=1.0/data.parquet
/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations/datekey=20210507/coeff=0.5/data.parquet
/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations/datekey=20210507/coeff=0.75/data.parquet
/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations/datekey=20210507/coeff=1.0/data.parquet
```

and would like to load these into a hive table as elegantly as possible. I know the typical solution for something like this is to load all the data into a non-partitioned table first, then transfer all the data to final table using dynamic partitioning as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148187/hive-loading-in-partitioned-table)

However, my files don't have the datekey and coeff values in the actual data, it's only in the filename since that's how it's partitioned. So how would I keep track of these values when I load them into the intermediate table?

One workaround would be to do a separate `load data inpath` query for each coeff value and datekey. This would not need the intermediate table, but would be cumbersome and probably not optimal.

Are there any better ways for how to do this?

Comment: can you not do `insert into new_tab(a,b,part_col) select x,part_col,y from old_table` ? Assuming that  your new table is differently partitioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical solution is to build external partitioned table on top of hdfs directory:

```
create external table table_name (
column1 datatype, 
column2 datatype,
...
columnN datatype 
)
partitioned by (datekey int,
                coeff float)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '/user/hive/warehouse/datascience.db/simulations'
```

After that, recover all partitions, this command will scan table location and create partitions in Hive metadata:

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;
```

Now you can query table columns along with partiion columns and do whatever you want with it: use as is, or load into another table using insert .. select .. , etc:

```
select 
    column1, 
    column2,
    ...
    columnN,
    --partition columns
    datekey,
    coeff
from table_name
where datekey = 20210506
;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works way better than what I was planning doing before!